# Specifying numeric ranges in zsh history

Tags: zsh, command-history

According to the docs I can tell the zsh history to print lines in a range.
The docs say "history [first [last]]"
I've tried "history a b" but that gives a too many arguments error.

I've also tried hundreds of other things same results. Can someone post an example of a working history with range?

Comment: That sounds like a `bash` error. Are you sure you're using `zsh`? What do `echo "$ZSH_VERSION"` and `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` tell you?

Comment: Works fine here: `echo "$ZSH_VERSION"; history 1008 1009` yields
`4.3.10
 1008  history 1000 1008
 1009  history 1008 1009`

Comment: ZSH_VERSION is 5.0.2 BASH_VERSION is null. Also I am using Oh-my-zsh.

Comment: What happens when you remove Oh-my-zsh? (You should remove it permanently, FWIW).

Answer (score 1):

Examples as requested.

Fails when attempting using `bash`:

```
mintvm ~ # echo $BASH_VERSION
4.3.11(1)-release
mintvm ~ # echo $ZSH_VERSION

mintvm ~ # history 1 5
-su: history: too many arguments
mintvm ~ #
```

Works when using `zsh`:

```
mintvm ~ # zsh
mintvm# echo $BASH_VERSION

mintvm# echo $ZSH_VERSION
5.0.2
mintvm# history 1 5
    1  echo $BASH_VERSION
    2  echo $ZSH_VERSION
    3  history 1 5
mintvm#
```

Answer (score 0):

## zsh

```
fc -l -5      # 5 most recent 
fc -l 1 5     # 5 oldest 
fc -l -10 -5  # 10th newest to 5 newest
```

Comment: Note that in `zsh`, `history` is the same as `fc -l`. The OP's problem is likely that they're using `bash` or oh-my-zsh incompatible `history` wrapper, not `zsh`.